# validate result of grep

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying with the below code to print  `Available` if there's a match, else `nil`

```
grep -o 'pattern' test.log | awk '{if($0=="pattern") print "Available"; else print "nil"}'
```

The `if` part is working fine, but I'm not getting the `else` part if the grepped out is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern did not match, then `grep` produces no output and the `awk` program has no data to work with.  This is why you will never get `nil` from the `awk` code.

Another way of doing this would be

```
if grep -q 'pattern' test.log; then
    echo 'Available'
else
    echo 'nil'
fi
```

The `-q` option of `grep` is used to stop the utility from generating any output (apart from possibly diagnostic output).  Here, we don't want output from `grep`, only its exit status.

---

With `awk`, you could still do your test if you wish, but you will have to output the `nil` string conditionally in an `END` block:

```
grep -o 'pattern' test.log |
awk '/pattern/ { print "Available"; found = 1 }
     END { if (!found) print "nil" }'
```

The `END` block will be executed even if the `awk` script does not get any input to work with.

In fact, you could do the whole thing with `awk`:

```
awk '/pattern/ { print "Available"; found = 1; exit }
     END { if (!found) print "nil" }' test.log
```

Calling `exit` will invoke the `END` block, so we can't get rid of the `found` variable.

Comment: i was doing with your first option. But i am looking for one-liner, the second option with awk works great ... Thanks.

Comment: @reddingr Why would you want a one-liner? You could use `grep -q 'pattern' test.log && echo 'Available' || echo 'nil'` if you feel so inclined.

Comment: Great!! not aware of option `-q` ... Thanks.